# Where could I find some network architecture courses or good books?

Tags: networking, architecture, scalability

The best source that I found is not really a course, is most like a blog with short stories about succed cases of architecture strategies in highscalability.com

My concern is if is there any good course or book about IT architecture strategies that I could trust?

Best,

Comment: Also see: http://serverfault.com/questions/1038/best-resource-for-it-architecture-training

Answer (score 2):

If anecdotes are what you learn best from, I would suggest reading "Practice of System and Network Administration". While the subject matter goes beyond actual network architecture, there are two chapters specifically that might interest you: Chapter 6 "Datacenters" and Chapter 7 "Networks". However, I believe that useful information about architectural decisions can be found throughout the book.

In fact, if you read the entire book you can consider yourself to have a degree in practical computer science. =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a course offered by a renowned network services vendor, such as Cisco.
It does cost a lot, but they teach you a lot, and you can also get a certificate which is valued.

For more - start doing it. Buy some switches, little routers, PCs, ... and put together three networks with several virtual machines, then impose some restrictions, traffic shaping and so on.

If you're not afraid of some unix, you can do it all in virutal world in Solaris, using Zones (really simple virtual "hosts") and Crossbow (virtual newtorking). There are a lot of manuals and online material on these.

In any case - enjoy!